# Insert a row without altering table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**TL;DR:** Is there a way of inserting a row to an intermediate "view" or "table" resulting from a subquery?

### **Background:**

I am not allowed to alter table in database (SQL Server 2014).

The table only records the start time of the task but for another query, I need to find out both the start time and end time of all tasks. I can take the liberty of tasks having no breaks in between them.

### **Problem**

I am able to get the start time and end time for all tasks *EXCEPT* for the last task by using a JOIN on a.row = b.row - 1.

I need to retrieve all tasks' start and end times, possibly by inserting a row in an intermediate query result "table" or "view" where the timestamp would be NOW().

### **Tables**

**INPUT TABLE**

```
TaskID    StartTime
-----------------------------
1         2018-08-10 03:00:00
2         2018-08-10 06:12:00
3         2018-08-11 07:13:00
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT TABLE**

```
TaskID    StartTime              EndTime
----------------------------------------------------------
1         2018-08-10 03:00:00    2018-08-10 06:12:00
2         2018-08-10 06:12:00    2018-08-11 07:13:00
3         2018-08-11 07:13:00    2018-08-16 15:26:00 (now)
```

**OUTPUT TABLE**

```
TaskID    StartTime              EndTime
----------------------------------------------------
1         2018-08-10 03:00:00    2018-08-10 06:12:00
2         2018-08-10 06:12:00    2018-08-11 07:13:00
```

### CURRENT NON-WORKING CODE

```
WITH EnterTaskTimes AS ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY StartTime ASC) TaskID
    , [Timestamp] AS StartTime 
    FROM TaskLog
), 
TaskTimes As (
    SELECT
    a.TaskID Task,
    a.StartTime StartTime,
    b.StartTime EndTime
    FROM TaskLog a JOIN TaskLog b
    ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID - 1
)
```

Thank you,

Comment: Just do a `UNION` and set the last record's `EndTime` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: I am confused..  Why are you using: `ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID - 1` as it probably should be: `ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID` ? It would seem a 1:1 match is needed.

Comment: @Leptonator I've done that because I want the StartTime of next task to be the EndTime of current task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Lead() function:

```
-- setup
Create Table Time_Lapse
(
    TaskID Int
    , StartTime DateTime
)

Insert Into dbo.Time_Lapse
(
    TaskID
    , StartTime
)
Select 1, '2018-08-10 03:00:00'
Union All Select 2, '2018-08-10 06:12:00'
Union All Select 3, '2018-08-11 07:13:00'


-- query
Select 
    tl.TaskID
    , tl.StartTime
    , Lead(tl.StartTime, 1, GetDate()) Over (Order By tl.StartTime) As EndTime
From dbo.Time_Lapse As tl
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about a Lead() function. Take the upvote

Comment: Was just about to post a nearly identical response. :)

Comment: @kpark I would suggest this approach over your accepted answer. Simpler and better for performance.

Comment: I've looked more into Lead() function and realized that now. Seems to be a lot cleaner way of doing it. Thanks, and I've marked it as accepted.

Comment: :)  You've "beaten" me a couple of times, @SeanLange - happy to return the favor.

Answer (score 2):

Without having tried, I think something like this should work to ‘extend’ your original table by one row

```
...
   Union
Select max(Taskid) as taskid , now() as StartTime
 From TaskLog
```

Comment: Since UNION didn't come come into mind at all. Take the upvote! Thank you